# XCTest UI tests: can not find collectionView within a table cell

Tags: ios, xctest

There is a cell contains a Collection View. I have set the cells within a Collection View using

```
cell.accessibilityLabel = @"daren_shangjia_0001_add_new_photo_album";
```

and then in XCTest, I do

```
print(app.debugDescription);
```

I didn't see the accessibilityLabel that I have provided.

```
Element subtree:
 →Application 0x608000367200: {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: '纳豆行'
    Window 0x608000365e80: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Other 0x608000365880: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
        Other 0x608000365b80: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
          Other 0x608000365700: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
            Other 0x608000364d40: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
              Other 0x608000364680: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
                Other 0x608000364740: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
                  Other 0x608000364800: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
                    NavigationBar 0x6080003648c0: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 44.0}}, identifier: '140'
                      Button 0x608000364980: traits: 8589934593, {{20.0, 31.0}, {20.7, 20.5}}, label: 'da ren list backBtn'
                      StaticText 0x608000365f40: traits: 8590000192, {{192.0, 28.0}, {30.0, 27.0}}, label: '140'
                      Button 0x608000366000: traits: 8589934593, {{360.7, 25.0}, {33.3, 33.1}}, label: 'denglu 0010 you ke register'
                    Other 0x608000366240: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
                      Other 0x6000003660c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
                        Other 0x600000365e80: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
                          Table 0x600000365dc0: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 680.8}}
                            Image 0x608000366a80: traits: 8589934596, {{0.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 219.6}}
                              Image 0x608000366cc0: traits: 8589934596, {{168.4, 135.2}, {77.3, 77.3}}
                                Button 0x608000367080: traits: 8589934593, {{151.8, 118.6}, {110.4, 110.4}}
                            Image 0x6080003672c0: traits: 8589934596, {{245.2, 195.3}, {16.6, 16.6}}, identifier: 'da_ren_list_girl'
```

Comment: What is the output of app.debugDescription? I have a suspicion about what is causing this but need to see the view hierarchy that is reported.

Comment: Body cannot contain " Elemen".

This looks like spam. And we don't like spam. Unless it's served with eggs and beans.

why stackoverflow not allow me to post the code? is it because too long?

Comment: Anyway, I added some in the original question, and some answer below. @Oletha

Comment: Do you get anything for app.cells.debugDescription? Is the cell inside the table view in a container view or is it directly beneath the table view in the view hierarchy? I would expect to see at least once cell in your debug output.

Comment: @Oletha
Find: Target Application 0x6080000a3c60
  Output: {
    Application 0x600000172840: {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: '纳豆行'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Cell
    Output: {
      Cell 0x6080001699c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 327.7}, {414.0, 185.4}}
      Cell 0x6080001678c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 557.3}, {414.0, 185.4}}, label: 'DaRenDetailCell_1'
    }

Comment: Does this strategy in my answer to this question (second answer) help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41985328/5052894

Comment: @Oletha after I follow your strategy, I can find element within cells. wonder why do we need to set cell.isAccessibilityElement = false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access a view within a container view, you must ensure that the container view is not accessible. In your case, I think this is the table view cell.

```
let cell: UITableViewCell!
cell.isAccessibilityElement = false
```

To reduce complexity for Accessibility users, there will be a maximum of one accessible view on any part of the screen. A cell is usually something which contains information which can be summarised as a single entity, for example, representing an item which includes text and a picture with the option to select it. Since you have decided to have quite a complex cell, you need to change the default behaviour of it to allow Accessibility users more granular access to the contents of the cell. It can no longer be summarised at the table view cell level. So the job of explaining what is on the screen must be passed to elements lower in the view hierarchy.

To further understand this concept, try using your app with VoiceOver turned on and use a triple three-finger tap to toggle the screen curtain.

Comment: It doesn't work in UI Testing since cell is a Type and not an instance can you elaborate ?

Comment: @PavelZagalsky The accessibility identifier needs to be added in the app code, not the test code.

Comment: I really got stuck writing UITests because of the behaviour you described here. I was just wondering if it is even possible at all to access a cell, from a collection view nested inside a table view, where you would have to scroll down first, and then to the right? 

Comment: If the collection view is nested directly inside the table view then it may not be possible. I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature in XCTest but it seems that any view nested inside a table view which isn't a table cell/header/footer cannot be seen by UI tests.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue as you. Hope this code will help you.

```
// Get the first Cell and don't forget to set id for your tableview
let tableCellContainer = app.tables["HomeTableView"].cells.element(boundBy: 1)

// Get collection cell which is has the text label inside is 'Brazil'
let cell = tableCellContainer.staticTexts["Brazil"] 

cell.tap()                          
XCTAssert(cell.exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

"tableView" - TableView Accessibility Identifier

"tableViewCell" - TableViewCell Containing CollectionView

"daren_shangjia_0001_add_new_photo_album" - Collection View Cell accessibility Identifier

```
let myTable = app.tables.matching(identifier: "tableView")
        let cell = myTable.cells.element(matching: .cell, identifier: "tableViewCell").firstMatch
        let element = cell.children(matching: .any).matching(identifier: "daren_shangjia_0001_add_new_photo_album")
        element.element.tap()
```