# How to access the `detailTextLabel` in a `tableViewCell` at UITests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I wanna check whether there is a `tableViewCell.detailTextLabel` with a given string in my UITest. The problem is when I search for `app.tables.cells.children(matching: .staticText)` it will only look for labels that are `tableViewCell.textLabel`. 
Any ideas on how to query for the `detailTextLabel`?

Comment: Please add the output for app.staticTexts.debugDescription

Comment: It outputs all the text that is in the `textLabel`s together with a label that is in the header of the tableView and the navigationBar title.

Comment: Or if this cell text is dynamic, you could locate the cell and list all its children with type `statictext` with `app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .staticText)` then find the child you want `app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .staticText).element(boundBy: {child index})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a more generic query to determine if the text exists at all. If you are trying to assert that a cell contains "123 Main St.", for example, you can use the following:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["123 Main St."]).exists)
```

Granted, if that text appears in the `textLabel` the test will still pass.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong then.. It works fine for the textLabels but not for the details..

Comment: It *does* work! The problem is that I was initializing the detailTextLabels with an empty string and then populating with the informations.. by the time the UITest was querying for the text it wasn't set yet. Everything is fine now!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your detail text label isn't accessible.

To see everything that's available to your tests in the view hierarchy, print the debug description of the following query, which may help you to understand whether the element is appearing, what its type is, and what its identifier or label is:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
print(app.descendants(matching: .any).debugDescription)
```

Make sure that the containing view (the cell?) is not accessible, and that the detail text label *is* accessible, and give it an identifier:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell!
cell.isAccessibilityElement = false
cell.detailTextLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
cell.detailTextLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "myDetailTextLabel"
```