# UIButton cannot be tapped under UITests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

The idea is simple. I have custom `UIButton`:

```
@IBDesignable class RadioButton: AttributedButton {

    private let attributedView = AttributedView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))

    @IBInspectable var isActive: Bool = false {

        didSet {

            attributedView.removeFromSuperview()

            attributedView.center = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
            attributedView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            attributedView.cornerRadius = 8

            attributedView.backgroundColor = isActive ? UIColor.scooter : UIColor.white
            attributedView.layer.borderColor = isActive ? UIColor.scooter.cgColor : UIColor.silver.cgColor
            addSubview(attributedView)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when `isActive = false`:

[image]

and `isActive = true`:

[image]

Everything works as expected when app is running. But the same I need to do under UITests. All I do is to perform tap on that button... but it is not tapped. Why?

How do I perform tap?

```
let termsRadioButton = app.buttons["termsRadioButton"]
termsRadioButton.tap()
```

Once I tap I check if `isActive = true`, if not, then I display an alert... alert should not be under uitests because I REALLY tap that button. What is wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the button is inside a cell or other container view, you will have to set the cell to be inaccessible for your button to be accessible.

See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038145/5052894

If you want to be able to check the state of the button from the UI tests, I suggest setting `isSelected` on the button, which is part of [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol), which UIButton inherits from. You can then access the state of the button using `XCUIElement.isSelected`.